# #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias? Error_mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1248

```
select (1- (s1 + s2 + s3) / (s4 + s5 + s6))*100,startdate
from (
  select sum(v1) as s1 ,sum(v2) as s2,sum(v3) as s3,sum(v4) as s4,sum(v5) as s5,sum(v6) as s6,startdate 
    from (
      select 
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfAal2TermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v1,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfIpTermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v2,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%TdmTermGrp%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfTdmTermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v3,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfAal2TermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v4,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfIpTermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v5,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%TdmTermGrp%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfTdmTermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v6,
        startdate
      from MGW1 
      group by startdate
    )
    group by startdate
  )
```

Comment: Please use the `edit` button below your question to make it readable. Use propper formatting, add details and the precise error message. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, you need to format that better.  But the answer is that any derived table must have a unique name.  Yours is either duped, or has no name.  I just can't find it in that mess.

Comment: The error message is pretty specific and clear. So what is your question?

Comment: After looking at it a little bit, it looks like the derived tables are nested.  That complicates it more.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select (1- (s1 + s2 + s3) / (s4 + s5 + s6))*100,startdate
from
(   select sum(v1) as s1 ,sum(v2) as s2,sum(v3) as s3,sum(v4) as s4,sum(v5) as s5,sum(v6) as s6,startdate 
    from
    (   select avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfAal2TermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v1,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfIpTermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v2,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%TdmTermGrp%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfTdmTermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v3,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfAal2TermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v4,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfIpTermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v5,
        avg(case when indicateur like '%TdmTermGrp%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfTdmTermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v6,
        startdate
        from MGW1
        group by startdate
    ) xDerived1 --  NEED AN ALIAS HERE
    group by startdate
) xDerived2 --  NEED AN ALIAS HERE
```

Note the two derived table names I snuck in (`xDerived1` and `xDerived2`). It gets past the Error Code 1248

Answer (score 0):

i have syntaxe error in line 11:

select (1- (s1 + s2 + s3) / (s4 + s5 + s6))*100 as succ_rate,startdate as Time
from
( select sum(v1) as s1 ,sum(v2) as s2,sum(v3) as s3,sum(v4) as s4,sum(v5) as s5,sum(v6) as s6,startdate
from
( select avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfAal2TermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v1,
avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfIpTermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v2,
avg(case when indicateur like '%TdmTermGrp%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfTdmTermsRej' then valeur else null end) as v3,
avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfAal2TermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v4,
avg(case when indicateur like '%Vmgw%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfIpTermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v5,
avg(case when indicateur like '%TdmTermGrp%' and compteur = 'pmNrOfTdmTermsReq' then valeur else null end) as v6,
startdate
from data where SUBSTR(date_format(startdate,'AAAA-%m-JJ HH:%m:%s'),1,10) like $P{date_debut} and MGW like $P{par_mgw}
group by startdate, MGW)